# Express middleware refrain static from going into next

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following function:

```
app.use('/Framework', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'Framework')));
app.get('/*/*', function (req, res, next) {
    ...code...
);
```

The request goes into both the `app.use` and the `app.get`. I'd like it that when I try to access a resource with `/Framework` it just gives it to me as static while ignoring the other functions from below. Yet when accessing static it seems to go in the `app.get`.
Why is this happening and how can I modify it to get the wanted behavior?

**Edit due to comment**

I also have a

```
app.use('/Public', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'Public')));
```

before which works perfectly as expected.
Requests such as : `/Public/0.png` work while requests such as `/Framework/0.png` enter both functions. I have checked the folders names over and over again and they are correct.

Comment: Can you specify wich url requests go througt both the static middleware and your custom route?

Answer (score 0):

Express-static is Express middleware. Middleware is chained together and after a middleware is done executing its code, it calls `next();` internally to allow the next middleware to execute. After all middleware is executed, the routes will be executed.

Since express-static calls `next();` after its done, the routes will be invoked and checked if any routes match the request. Since your request `/Public/0.png` matches your route `/*/*` the route is executed.

- My suggestion would be to try an rename your route from `/*/*` to something more specific.
- You could try regex for the route which would explicitly allow any requests matching `/*/*` but would refuse any routes which have a file extension appended to it (i.e. `/*/*.png`).
- Another (hacky) way would be to check for [headersSent](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.headersSent) inside your `/*/*` route before executing the code within that route.

A side-note:

Seeing how your route name (e.g. *Public* and *Framework*) are the same as your directory names, you could simply do

`app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, PARENT_DIRECTORY)));`

Where PARENT_DIRECTORY is the parent directory of both `Public` and `Framework`. This way

Your directory structure would look like this:

```
Directory
|
| ---- Public
| ---- Framework
```

And any requests to `Public` would end up serving files from your `Public` directory, same for the `Framework` directory respectively.